# kendo grid combobox - how to use hidden columns in the grid itself as a datasource for combobox

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

Using the Kendo Grid...

I have one column in the grid whereby the contents of the dropdown box need to be dynamic per row (but there will always be only 2 options).  Instead of making another call to another datasource for each row, I would like to use a couple hidden columns that exist in the grid as the data source for the combobox.  How might I accomplish that ?

Thanks !

```
    '{ field: 'Uom' ,  editor: function(container, options) {
    $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoComboBox({
    dataSource:  [{ Id:"1" ,Uom: "How to use field X from grid here"  },
                  { Id:"2" ,Uom: "How to use field Y from grid here"  }]   ,
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataTextField: "Uom",
    autobind: false
    });
    }  
    }'
```